# Why block .catch(error => { is not run on not found error in axios request?

Tags: javascript, laravel, axios

In laravel 9 app with axios 0.25 when making request to server

```
axios.post(route('frontend.get_block_cms_item'), filters)
    .then(({data}) => {
        main_page_contact_us_title.value = data.cMSItem.title
        main_page_contact_us_text.value = data.cMSItem.text
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error)
    })
```

I use code when item is not found :

```
    public function get_block_cms_item(Request $request)
    {
        $key     = $request->key;
        $cMSItem = CMSItem
            ::getByKey($key)
            ->getByPublished(true)
            ->first();
        if (empty($cMSItem)) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'CMS Item with key "' . $key . '" not found !',
                404
            ]);
        }
```

but code .then(({data}) => is called and I got run time error :

```
typeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')
```

I expected that

```
.catch(error => {
```

must be run and I will not get error...

How that can be fixed ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the status code from the network tab, I'm sure it's 200. Now the question is, why is it 200 and not 404?

Comment: maybe try accessing the response object and check the return code manually

Comment: Did you check what you actually get back from the network request? Is it a 404 or is it a success where the data doesn't match what you expect?

Comment: Actually, I don't see your `get_block_cms_item` responding to a success.

Comment: What I meant to say is that you'd have more luck of receiving good answers if you edit the question and you make it refer to Laravel only

Comment: That was misspelling in my code : I have to write : [], 404